# Showing that $H$ is a normal subroup of $A_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutation-cycles

Consider the subgroup

$H$={$(1),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)$}

How would I show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $A_4$?

If I perform a few computations such as:
$$(132)^{-1}(12)(34)(132)=(123)(12)(34)(123)=(14)(23)$$
$$(243)^{-1}(12)(34)(243)=(234)(12)(34)(243)=(13)(24)$$
$$(124)^{-1}(12)(34)(124)=(142)(12)(34)(124)=(12)(34)$$

,then we see that an element of the form $\beta^{-1}\alpha\beta$, where $\beta \in A_4$ and $\alpha \in H$, remains in $H$.

But because it's tedious to show all the other cases, how would one prove this without showing all the cases?

Comment: Have you verified that $H$ is a subgroup?

Comment: It was implied in the question that it's a subgroup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Conjugation preserves the cycle type (this spares you quite some computation) and here you even only have one non-trivial cycle type.

Comment: Actually, any group automorphism preserves the cycle type.

Comment: Good point even if not needed here.

Comment: Because the subgroup has order 4 and the sum of the sizes of the conjugacy classes has to be of order 4 as well then?  But then I'm not sure why the $(2,2)$ cycles in $A_4$ wouldn't work then.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to say to be honest. What I wrote hold in general if you are considering conjugation inside the symmetric group (hence also in subgroups). All cycles of type $(2,2)$ are already in your group $H$ (its quite easy to see that you cannot have more of this type if you stay inside of $S_4$, i.e. use four symbols). If you now know that conjugation preserves the cycle type, then you are done.

Comment: Well just the $(2,2)$ cycles in $A_4$ do not work because you do not have an identity then. If you now add the identity (which becomes your $H$ then) everything is fine.

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to understand what you meant by conjugation preserving the cycle type.  So you're saying that for $\beta^{−1}\alpha\beta=c$, because $\alpha$ and $c$ are conjugates, they'll always be the same order regardless of what $\beta \in A_4$ I pick?

Comment: Don't worry, I did not want to be rude or mean or anything. Not only same order, same type (which is stronger since there are elements of different type and same order) and yes, that is what I am saying.

Comment: Thanks for the help in trying to understand!